# Enable USB Debugging for Android LG Enact

Tags: android

I'm trying to deploy to a Verizon branded LG Enact (VS890 4G) running Android 4.4.2 but `adb devices` won't list the device.

I've enabled developer mode and usb debugging on the device, added the VID to adb_usb.ini, restarted ADB, and uninstalled and re-installed my device from device manager, and tried it with different cables and even on a different machine (a Mac) yet `adb devices` won't display my device.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

For that particular device you apparently don't connect with MTP.  Instead you need to select "Internet connection" as the connection type.  In other words Settings -> PC connection -> Select USB connection method -> Internet connection -> "Ethernet".